# Searching line of a file with Python

Tags: python, json

I am writing some code to read a file and assign certain lines to be moved to another file.

I need it to read until it finds an ID, then read through until it either finds a property OR until it reaches the end of that ID. I used a while not in line function. The ID I am testing with only has a single child with the property name. But the entire file has four. I would like it to only use that specific ID's child, but it runs all the way through the file and uses all four instances. What can I do so that it actually stops after it reaches the end of the ID. I will include the example text I am using at the bottom.

```
import os
import json
import shutil
import re
d='.'
folders = list(filter (lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)), 
os.listdir(d)))
print("Folders found: ")
print(folders)



def processModelFolder(inFolder):

          fileName = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + ".mdl")
          fileNameTwo = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + ".vg2.json")
          fileNameThree = os.path.join(d, inFolder, inFolder + "APPENDED.vg2.json")

          shutil.copyfile(fileNameTwo, fileNameThree)

          mdl = open(fileName , "r")
          json = open(fileNameTwo , "r")
          jsonCopy = open(fileNameThree , "r+")

          IDs = ["6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd"]
          Properties = ["IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_ANIMATION_TIME[0]"]

          for i in IDs:
              for line in mdl:
                  if i in line:
                      ID = i
                      print(ID)
                      while "[/" not in line:
                          for y in Properties:
                              for line in mdl:
                                  if y in line:
                                      name = y
                                      print(name)









for modelFolder in folders:   
        processModelFolder(modelFolder)
```

subset of mdl file:

```
[IDCO_CALCOBJECT_DATA]     

IDCO_IDENTIFICATION = "6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd"

IDCO_DESIGNATION = "Stirnradgetriebe"

[IDSCO_CALCULATION]

IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_ANIMATION_TIME[0] = 2.0

[/IDO_SYSTEM_LOADCASE] [0]
```

Comment: Please show the mdl file (or a subset of it)

Comment: This is a subset of the mld                                     [IDCO_CALCOBJECT_DATA]

IDCO_IDENTIFICATION = "6ff0010c-00fe-485b-b695-4ddd6aca4dcd"

IDCO_DESIGNATION = "Stirnradgetriebe"

[IDSCO_CALCULATION]

IDCO_DYNAMIC_SIMULATION_RESULTS_VISUALIZATION_RESPONSE_ANIMATION_TIME[0] = 2.0

[/IDO_SYSTEM_LOADCASE] [0]

Comment: Please format it as code so we can easily read it.

Comment: Ok, I have now.

Comment: Can you please post a file with few 'sections' so it will be clear how a 'section' (identified by 'IDCO_IDENTIFICATION') start|ends

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel like I have not been particularly clear on this thread. I have rewritten my question in a way I feel is much easier. This is the link if you would be so kind as to continue helping me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908387/using-python-to-search-an-mdl-file-for-key-words

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use a threading model, i.e. a multithreaded **Python** application.
One thread to read the file and when a matching line for your criteria is found, queue it in a queue.
Let another worker thread pick it up and process the children.